# Trying to understand some stuff with classes and an array issue

Tags: ruby

Ruby newbie here. The following code does not work.

```
class Shows 
    def echo
        x, y, z = self
        puts x
        puts y
        puts z
    end
end

["Foo", 2, 2001].echo
```

This does.

```
class Array 
    def echo
        x, y, z = self
        puts x
        puts y
        puts z
    end
end

["Foo", 2, 2001].echo
```

My understanding was I could make Shows an inheritance of Arrays by

```
class Shows < Arrays
```

But that does not work either.

I know I can just create a method and use it like this

```
def echo(x, y, c)

    puts x
    puts y
    puts z
 end
```

However there's a reason I'd like to do it like in the first bit of code.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped, or if you have any follow up questions you would like answered.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I have a better understanding of Class use now and that what I hoped to do cannot be done with first instantiating an instance.

Answer (score 2):

In your first bit of code, you're constructing an Array and then attempting to call `#echo` on it, when `echo` is not defined on `Array`. You are closer with the idea to subclass `Array`, but you still have to instantiate a `Shows` instance, not an `Array` instance!

You can do it something like this:

```
# Create a new class called Shows, which is a subclass of Array
class Shows < Array
  def echo
    # In this case, since self is an Array subclass structure, you can use
    # destructuring assignment to assign to x, y, and z
    x, y, z = self
    puts x
    puts y
    puts z
  end
end

# Create a new Shows instance, passing in an array of values that should populate it.
# This works because Shows#initialize inherits from Array#initialize, which accepts an
# array as an input value.
Shows.new(["Foo", 2, 2001]).echo
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first bit of code doesn't work is the class of `["Foo", 2, 2001]` is an Array. The only way you will get that to work is if you write some code to initialize a show object. For example you could do something like:

```
s = Show.new("Foo", 2, 2001)
s.echo
```

And to do this would would need to something like this:

```
class Show

  def initialize(name, day, year)
    @name = name
    @day = day
    @year = year
  end

  def echo
    puts @name
    puts @day
    puts @year
  end
end
```

This works because now you would be creating a new show object and then calling show on that object. Also as a best practice not, I would generally advice that you don't edit the Array class (or string, int...) in ruby since it can make things confusing down the road.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of inheritance in Ruby is that classes lower down the hierarchy (or "subclasses") have access to (or "inherit") the features of classes higher up. Subclasses can also add specific features of their own.

Consider the following code:

```
class Shows 
    def echo
        x, y, z = self
        puts x
        puts y
        puts z
    end
end

["Foo", 2, 2001].echo # => NoMethodError: undefined method `echo' for ["Foo", 2, 2001]:Array
```

The `[]` syntax is an array literal. It is the equivalent of `Array.new`. Therefore, this:

```
["Foo", 2, 2001]       # => ["Foo", 2, 2001]

["Foo", 2, 2001].class # => Array
```

could be more tediously written like this:

```
a = Array.new    # => []
a << "Foo"       # => ["Foo"]
a << 2           # => ["Foo", 2]
a << 2001        # => ["Foo", 2, 2001]

a.class          # => Array
```

I only show you this longer version so that it's easier to see that this:

```
["Foo", 2, 2001].echo
```

is sending the `echo` message to an object of the class `Array`, but `echo` is only defined in the class `Shows`.

Likewise, the following code suffers from the same problem:

```
class Shows < Array
    def echo
        x, y, z = self
        puts x
        puts y
        puts z
    end
end

["Foo", 2, 2001].echo # => NoMethodError: undefined method `echo' for ["Foo", 2, 2001]:Array
```

While the class `Shows` now inherits all of the features from the class `Array`, we never send the `echo` message to an object of the class `Shows` -- we sent the message to an object of the class `Array`.

Thus, only your example below will behave in the way you expect:

```
class Array 
    def echo
        x, y, z = self
        puts x
        puts y
        puts z
    end
end

["Foo", 2, 2001].echo # => Foo
                      # => 2
                      # => 2001
```

In some cases, subclassing a core Ruby class like `Array` isn't necessarily a bad decision. You should do it with an understanding of the consequences though. Check out this article: [Beware subclassing Ruby core classes, by Steve Klabnik](http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes).